# How to consume a Complex Type WCF web service from Java?

Tags: java, web-services, wcf, soap

Help!

I need to consume a WCF Web Service from java. The Service:

- Cannot be modified.
- Uses **CustomBinding**.
- The Binding configuration is meant to allow communication only over HTTPS.
- The authenticationMode of the Binding is **UserNameOverTransport**
- Has userNameAuthentication (user / password) on SOAP Headers.
- The return type is a Complex Type.

I have written many C# clients for this service before, even consumed it from PHP (with cURL), but I'm really struggling to write a java client for it.

I've already tried with **JAX-WS** and **Axis** with no success. I'm trying to avoid creating a client that appends a String to form the SOAP envelope and send it in an HTTP request.

***Note:** Due to NDA, I cannot provide the URL of Web Service's WSDL, so, if you're willing to help, please tell me what else can I do for you to know more about the Web Service.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: While it may introduce redundancy and complexity, I would be tempted to create a wrapper service in C#. This would consume the service operation and expose a more orthodox SOAP 1.1 operation over basicHttpBinding, which is much more interoperable.

Comment: Thanks @tom. I should not use any wrapper, in order to avoid more "movable parts". I created some classes using javax xml classes to create a SOAP, and sending it over an HTTP POST request.

So, basically, I had to write the proxy. It is working fine tough.

Comment: Glad you got it working...